# Shortest path point to point Error

Tags: pyqgis, shortest-path, voronoi-thiessen

I'm new in Python and QGIS

I try to build the shortest path in a line layer and got an error "There is no route from start point to end point" because of point line projection.

I'm trying to find the shortest path from start point to end point on a graph (line layer). To do this, I built a polygon skeleton and then projected the start and end points onto this skeleton using the following geometric expression

```
shortest_line(
    @geometry, 
        aggregate('1 graph Voronoj', 'collect', @geometry)
)
```

like this

[image]

Then I tried to split green line by red line, but nothing has happened (I think it's not normal and due this I have problem with shortest path algorythm). I've created new extended red line to do this using such expression

```
extend( 
    shortest_line(
        @geometry, 
            aggregate('1 graph Voronoj', 'collect', @geometry)
    )
,0,1)
```

And I got 2 lines instead of the one
[image]

Then I combined the red and green layers into one layer and got a graph from start to end point. And I got an error "There is no route from start point to end point". I think that the reason is the shortest_line from point to voronoy graph do not intersect. But I need correct shortest line because I want to automate this actions through PyQGIS.

How could I build a correct projection a point onto my graph to find a shortest path?

[image]

I have loaded my project here . Please, watch it https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xBPrv6bbdwMYPlu6fViC2g9aHiQWlEeN?usp=sharing

Through Snapping I get such Shortest path (only between point projection), it's better but not from start and end points. When I try to calculate path between start and end points I got the same error.
[image]

Comment: Note there is a difference between pyqgis and gis expressions. It is not the same. I guess you are not actually looking for a pyqgis solution? About your issue: there is no path because of a missing node at the intersection point.

Comment: I'm looking both solution. Now I'm trying to realize shortest path search through qgis expression. But in the future I want to automate through pyqgis

Comment: Could you explain how I can add node? It's a line layer and I have splitted the horyzontal line into 2 lines (yellow line in the second screenshot). All of my line layer - is the simplest lines between two points. Is it not enough? What should I do?

Comment: Now I have a big problem with point projection and I have to redraw them manually. May be there is some desion from PyQGIS? It is more important for me

Comment: Try [snapping](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgissnapgeometries) the layer to itself

Comment: I tried and used different modes of Snapping but I got the same error - There is no route from start point to end point. If I choose not projected verticles there is a way from start to end point

Comment: (You've created the red line layer right, it is not just a styling layer? You need to merge the red line layer with the green.) Try Dissolve, then Explode lines

Comment: Your way works. May be I did something wrong at the first time) Thank you!

Comment: Could you, please, to help me to rewrite geometry expression (shortest line) from QGIS expression to PyQGIS expression? My way doesn't work

Comment: from qgis.core import *
import processing
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point, LineString
line_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('lines')[0]
line_feature = line_layer.getFeature(0)
line = [p for p in line_feature.geometry().asMultiPolyline()]
points_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("points")[0]
points_features = points_layer.getFeatures()
points = [Point(feature.geometry().asPoint()) for feature in points_features]
vl = QgsVectorLayer(f"LineString?crs={line_layer.crs().authid()}", "linelayer", "memory")

Comment: provider = vl.dataProvider()
for point in points:
  wkt = QgsGeometry.fromWkt(point).shortestLine(QgsGeometry.fromWkt(line)).asWkt()
  print(wkt)
  new_feature = QgsFeature() 
  new_feature.setGeometry(wkt)
  prov.addFeatures([new_feature])
  vl.updateExtents()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl)

Comment: I also have a problem when I just copy a QGIS command

Comment: from qgis.core import *
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point, LineString

line_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('line')[0]
line_feature = line_layer.getFeature(0)
line = [p for p in line_feature.geometry().asMultiPolyline()]

Comment: output = QgsProject.instance().readPath("./") + "/Projected_points3.shp";
processing.run("native:geometrybyexpression", {'INPUT': line_layer,'OUTPUT_GEOMETRY':1,'WITH_Z':False,'WITH_M':False,'EXPRESSION':"shortest_line(\r\n    @geometry, \r\n        aggregate('pasted_features_17889dfc_997b_4fb0_ba83_a79590279e97', 'collect', @geometry)\r\n)\r\n",'OUTPUT':output})
polygon_layer = QgsVectorLayer(output, "Projected_points3", "ogr")
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(polygon_layer)

Comment: Through processing.run QGIS freezes and then appends nothing